# merge cells in dataframe while converting to html using style object

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, styles, cell

I am trying to merge cells in dataframe while converting to HTML. But however, ending with row lines. Is it possible to merge only specific cells in a dataframe while converting to HTML or can we give header option to multiple columns, but not with lines? It should be header.

While converting to html am using style function

```
th_props = [
                            ('border', '1px solid black'),
                          ('border-collapse','collapse')
                          ]
                styles = [
                          dict(selector="th", props=th_props),
                          dict(selector="td", props=th_props)
                          
                          ]
 lic_data.style.applymap(self.color_negative_red, subset=['Utilised Percentage']).hide_index().set_table_styles(styles).render() )
```

In the Application column, I want to merge all three columns and only map title should be there without lines.
Otherwise, if I drop the Application column I need Map as header to remaining columns.

Let me know if there is any way to do that, or if this is not possible.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J11HB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to do this. But I tried to add caption to table as an option and its very feasible than this.

```
styles = [dict(selector="th", props=th_props), dict(selector="td", props=th_props), dict(selector="caption", props=[("text-align", "center"),                              ("font-weight", "bold"), ("font-size", "120%"),("color", 'orange')])] 

lic_data.style.applymap(self.color_negative_red, subset=['% Utilized']).hide_index().set_table_styles(styles).set_caption('caption').render() )
```